# Why does Python remove numbers randomly from array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, python-2.7

I am trying to solve a complex problem on HackerRank.com that involves creating a solution that accepts both small and large arrays of data ranging from 10 integers to 99,000 integers in length.

Find the problem here -> https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/array-and-simple-queries

**The Problem**

How to put this simple is that I have take a array, copy a range of numbers from that array that the user specifies, then append it to a new array.

```
 i = 2
 j = 4

 a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

 for numbers in range(i, j + 1):
     b.append(a[numbers - 1])
```

The range of numbers is appended to the b[] array. This should be 2, 3, 4 in the above example. Now I want to remove() the 2, 3, 4 from the a[] array. This is where I run into problems.

```
 for numbers in range(i, j + 1):
     a.remove(a[i-1])
```

This should remove numbers 2, 3, 4 and leave the a[] array as 1, 5, 6, 7, 8. This works in most cases as specified.

However, in larger arrays such as 500 in length. I see that a.remove() randomly removes numbers not in the range of i, j + 1.

*Example*

```
i = 239
j = 422
```

It removes a[47] and places it in another position as well removes i through j. I have NO IDEA why a[47] is being removed with the code specified above. Is remove() buggy?

**What I Need Help On**

I'm not trying to have the problem solved for me. I'm trying to understand why remove() is not working correctly. Logic says that it should not be removing anything from i through j, yet it is. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that it works for the small example at all? I get `[1, 3, 5, 7, 8]` instead. Which is actually what I expected, because I remember making exactly the same mistake ;)

Comment: Also, 1) what do you expect `.remove()` to do? Specifically, what does its argument mean? And 2) after removing an element from an array, what "happens" to the indices of other elements in the array?

Comment: I was told to do a.remove(i-1) and not a.remove(a[i-1])

Comment: Yeah, the removal works on most all test cases but the bigger ones. I'm going to try the above correction and see if that works.

Comment: @Rhymoid: The problem states that you need to select a range of numbers from the a[] array between i and j. Then you take that range of numbers and re-order them in the array. Either putting them to the front or back of the array. The remove() is because I'm removing the range i to j from the array because they are going to be appended() later to either the front or back.

Comment: From the problem statement, I interpret `i` and `j` to be indices. In Python, the `.remove(x)` method on lists removes the first occurrence of the *value* `x` in the list. If you want to delete part of the list, use the `del` operator (e.g. `del a[5]` to delete the sixth element, and `del a[1:4]` to delete the second, third, and fourth elements).

Comment: Thanks Rhymoid. Please paste that as the answer if you will. del a[i-1:j] worked and now my algorithm is passing. Unfortunately, the test cases where 99,000 value array is timing out. So, I guess I need to use NumPy instead of stock Python arrays? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.remove` method on arrays doesn't remove elements by their index, but their value. If you want to delete part of the list, use the `del` operator (e.g. `del a[5]` to delete the sixth element, and `del a[1:4]` to delete the second, third, and fourth elements).

(As for solving this problem efficiently: if you look at the operations in reverse order, I think you don't have to actually manipulate an array.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. del was what I would looking for to slice and delete from a single array rather than copying to a new array and using .remove()